# Pyspark: Conditionally overwrite an old record with a new value

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to update my dataframe based on the condition 'backfill'. If a record has a reason 'backfill', I want to update the 'data' column with the new 'data' but keep the old 'timestamp' value.

Ex:

```
id,reason,created_at,updated_at,app_data
2,registration,2020-05-09 15:57:19,2020-05-09 15:57:19,bat
2,disqualified ,2020-05-09 15:57:26,2020-05-09 15:57:26,cat
2,backfill,2021-04-29 17:47:09,2021-04-29 17:47:09,rat
```

should become

```
id,reason,created_at,updated_at,app_data
2,registration,2020-05-09 15:57:19,2020-05-09 15:57:19,bat
2,disqualified ,2020-05-09 15:57:26,2020-05-09 15:57:26,rat
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

We made the [Fugue project](https://github.com/fugue-project/fugue) to port native Python or Pandas code to Spark or Dask. This lets you can keep the logic very readable by expressing it in native Python. Fugue can then port it to Spark for you with one function call.

First, we'll tackle this problem in Pandas then port the code over to Spark. Here I create a DataFrame from your sample:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [2,2,2], "reason": ["registration", "disqualified", "backfill"],
                    "created_at": ["2020-05-09 15:57:19", "2020-05-09 15:57:26", "2021-04-29 17:47:09"],
                    "updated_at": ["2020-05-09 15:57:19", "2020-05-09 15:57:26", "2021-04-29 17:47:09"],
                    "app_data": ["bat", "cat", "rat"]})
```

Next, I create a function that does it for me in Pandas. I think this is right but if it's not, I think it should be easy to edit the logic.

```py
def backfill(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    cols = df.columns
    df['next_reason'] = df['reason'].shift(-1)
    df['new_data'] = df['app_data'].shift(-1)
    df.loc[df['next_reason'] == "backfill", "app_data"] = df.loc[df['next_reason'] == "backfill"]["new_data"]
    df = df.dropna()
    return df[cols]
```

Now we can test this using the Fugue `transform` function:

```py
from fugue import transform
transform(df, backfill, schema="*", partition={"by":"id", "presort": "created_at asc"})
```

Notice the partition keyword argument. This handles grouping by id and sorting by the timestamp so that the diff is accurate. Spark does not guarantee order when you move data around so you need to specify this.

And we can confirm the output is right. Now, we just need to bring it to Spark by specifying the engine:

```py
import fugue_spark
sdf = transform(df, backfill, schema="*", engine="spark", partition={"by":"id", "presort": "created_at asc"})
sdf.show()
```

and this outputs:

```
+---+------------+-------------------+-------------------+--------+
| id|      reason|         created_at|         updated_at|app_data|
+---+------------+-------------------+-------------------+--------+
|  2|registration|2020-05-09 15:57:19|2020-05-09 15:57:19|     bat|
|  2|disqualified|2020-05-09 15:57:26|2020-05-09 15:57:26|     rat|
+---+------------+-------------------+-------------------+--------+
```

Note `.show()` is needed because Spark evaluates lazily. The `transform` function can take in both Pandas and Spark dataframes and will output a Spark dataframe if you are using the Spark engine.

The code is likely more maintainable and easier than the PySpark equivalent.